# R 3.2.4 RSelenium findElements, on Windows 8 --UnknownError when inside function

Tags: r, rselenium

When I try to run the following lines with a single command

```
mybrowser$navigate("http://www.decolar.com/shop/flights/results/roundtrip/BSB/VCP/2016-06-15/2016-06-19/1/0/0")
eprice <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'css selector',"#clusters .price-amount" )
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException
```

However, when I run the last line alone after the error it works just fine:

```
> eprice <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'css selector',"#clusters .price-amount" )
> summary(eprice)
      Length Class      Mode
 [1,] 1      webElement S4  
 [2,] 1      webElement S4  
 [3,] 1      webElement S4  
 [4,] 1      webElement S4  
 [5,] 1      webElement S4  
 [6,] 1      webElement S4  
 [7,] 1      webElement S4  
 [8,] 1      webElement S4  
 [9,] 1      webElement S4  
[10,] 1      webElement S4
```

I want to run these lines inside a function so that I can get the flight prices from the site but they don’t work automatically. I’ve tried to set `Sys.sleep(4)` and `mybrowser$setImplicitWaitTimeout(4)`  between them and it didn’t work.

When inside function the error trackback is as follows:

```
 Error:      Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException 
5 stop(errMessage, call. = FALSE) 
4 checkStatus() 
3 queryRD(paste0(serverURL, "/session/", sessionInfo$id, "/elements"), 
    "POST", qdata = toJSON(list(using = using, value = value)), 
    json = TRUE) 
2 mybrowser$findElements(using = "css selector", "#clusters .price-amount") 
1 getPrices()
```

Comment: I've had this problem before, always caused by delays in the loading of the page. Try the commands inside a for loop and check what value of `Sys.sleep` works best. On certain pages I've had to have as much as 11.

Comment: Thanks! If you’re interested, I found a way to workaround the problem by  using two try blocks like follows: 
`try(eprice <- mybrowser$findElements(using = 'css selector',"#clusters .price-amount"), silent = T)`